# Is there a big difference between different opamps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass

I'm trying to build a lowpass filter for a line level signal (from the headphone jack of a phone or laptop) for sampling with an Arduino.

I found this [filter calculator](https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/) and input the specifications that I want.

Unfortunately, the chips they mention aren't listed on Amazon and I'm not really sure where to get them. I'd like something that I could go to a store and get, or get from Amazon within the next week or two. I'm not really sure what makes op amps different from each other besides voltage supply requirements.  I will be powering it from the Arduino so I don't have a dual supply and need 0V ground 5V power.

Circuit diagram of 4th order Butterworth low-pass filter 40Hz:

[image: Circuit diagram of 4th order Butterworth low-pass filter 40hz]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Could I use the same circuit but with something like the [LM358N](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082HMTTQX) instead?

Comment: Yes there are big differences if you read the specs. But you can try anything.

Comment: You can order about 20,000 different op amps from each of the major distributors.  Most distributors have parametric search options and those search options can teach you what the differences are between the various parts.  Try sites like Digikey.com or mouser.com. They each allow orders of single parts from individuals - you don't have to be a business to order.  Usually $7-$12 for shipping.  Order some resistors, caps, arduinos, ... for no extra shipping.

Comment: In the USA [Digikey](https://digikey.com) has US$5 shipping for small orders.  Personally I prefer [Mouser](https://mouser.com) (US$8 shipping).

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I read the specs, but I'm not really sure what half of it means and which parameters are important for my application... I have no way of knowing if the LTC6081 suggested by the filter wizard would be good for my application either.

Comment: Given that the LTC6081 is only available in SMD packages it probably isn't (physically) a good choice.  If you want to breadboard your circuit look for something in a DIP package.

Comment: Lots of designs for audio filters out there.  If you don't want to take the time to learn how to design one yourself, reusing someone else's design is a good idea.  Often it is a good idea even if you know how to design yourself.

Comment: for simple consumer audio hacking it doesn't really much matter, an old school lm358 will cover most uses. expect to pay more for features like "high current" outputs, low quiescent current, rail to rail outputs, better high frequency handling, lower  noise measurements, and so on.

Comment: We start to learn with transistors to understand how they are nonlinear then linearized the gain with resistors and ratios and negative feedback. Have you learnt that homework?  or just jumping into Op Amps. Think about clipping range, distortion, current limit, input bias current, input offset voltage and learn these.

Comment: Just so we're not giving undue preference to a few vendors, Newark (Newark.com) and Allied Electronics (alliedelec.com) are also possible sources.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that filter wizard doesn't give you a circuit that works. It only calculates the values needed for a given response, but that's usually far from a working filter circuit. What you have shown won't work, even with LTC6081. The circuit sets the common mode voltage at 0V, and it should be somewhere in the middle of the input and output voltage range, so about 2.5V for the LTC6081 (can be different for others, like LM358).

> Is there a big difference between different opamp chips?

Yes, there are huge differences in general.

In your application in particular, the concerns are:

1. Gain-bandwidth product: for the filter to be accurate, the GBW of the op-amp needs to be many times higher than the frequencies of interest.
2. Input and output voltage range.

Now let's compare LTC6081 vs LM358 in those respects:

1. 3.6MHz vs 0.7Mhz - OK-ish for this application, since your filter's frequencies of interest are orders of magnitude lower (40Hz).
2. I/O voltage range: here lies trouble. LTC6081 are rail-to-rail input/output op-amps. Their input *and* output voltage range goes from 0V to 5V in your circuit. LM358 is nothing like that. Its input range is 0V to about 3.5V, and output range is from 0V to about 2V, and somewhat higher with a pull-up resistor on the output.

Thus, yes, you could use LM358, but the common mode voltage should be set between 1..1.5V, and you can only get about 2V of usable output signal amplitude without distortion, as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4L8Lg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The pull-ups R8 and R9 extend the output voltage range of LM358 and reduce distortion somewhat. They could be probably reduced to 2kOhm.

To get a higher amplitude signal, you'd need to add a gain stage, or redesign the filter to have gain higher than 1.

The frequency response is approximately as shown below:

[image: Bode amplitude plot]

The time-domain response to a 40Hz square wave looks as follows:

[image: 40Hz square wave response]

Comment: The first paragraph is a little sideways.  The fault isn't in the tool, which assumes a two-rail arrangement.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The tool doesn't need to assume anything. You give it the supply rail voltages, that it then proceeds to ignore when choosing the operating point. It's definitely misleading in this respect.

Comment: Odd.  The help button over the Supply selection box specifically says the tool will supply a mid-rail reference when specifying single supply.  Must be a bug

Comment: @ScottSeidman That bug isn't the only thing. AC coupling - if needed - isn't shown either. It's a super-handy tool if you know what you're doing. Hardly a "breadboard ready" solution though.

Comment: AC coupling *is* a high-pass filter.  I wouldn't expect that in a filter design tool.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I tried building your circuit however it isn't working with the LM386. I found some LM358s and it doesn't seem to be working with those either, I probably messed something up lol.

Comment: LM386 is not an op-amp, it's an audio power amplifier - a completely different beast. I'll try putting it together using LM358 and see how it goes. I do expect it to work, we'll see if I'll eat my words :) Make sure the LM358s you use are genuine. Fakes are often completely different parts, with different common mode and output voltage ranges, a different output stage, etc. - and require different tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Dave Jones did an excellent introductory video on this topic:

["OpAmps Tutorial - What is an Operational Amplifier?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FYHt5XviKc)

It covers all the basics of op-amp theory, selection, and use.

(Apologies for the link-only answer)

Comment: There's also his video [The TOP 5 Jellybean OPAMP's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq1DMWtjL2U).

Answer (score 0):

The LM358 is never used for audio:

1. Too noisy (hissss).
2. Crossover distortion.
3. Poor high frequency response and slew rate.
   Audio opamps are used for audio.

It is like the difference between a Name Brand alkaline AA battery cell and a Super Heavy Duty poor quality battery cell made "over there".

Comment: *never used for audio* - this application is hardly audio. It's good enough. It's used in a **40Hz low-pass filter**. The 1/f noise is only of concern, and it's not outlandish. Slew rate and high-freq response are also of little concern. Crossover distortion can be worked around by forcing class-A operation of the output stage - with a sufficiently low pull-up in this case. *This thing is going to feed into an 8-10 bit ADC of an Arduino*. LM358 can definitely keep up at 40Hz.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't entirely have an answer to the question "Is there a big difference between opamps" but the voltage supply requirements are very important.

TLDR; if you need to filter negative voltage, you need a negative power supply.

I ended up using a 2nd Order low pass filter with a TL081P opamp. It turns out that you need negative power supply voltage to properly filter line level signal which which is around +2 to -2 volts. I built the circuit from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/614817/133023) and it didn't work, probably because of the negative voltage thing.

Here is the circuit I used [image: circuit diagram]

Here is what the finished product looked like (ignore the shoddy soldering)

[image: printed circuit board]

I used this board [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07SJ4ZXYQ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SJ4ZXYQ) to get +- 5 volt power input from an arduino.